# WordPress plugin development - adding action inside __construct() function

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I am not sure how to add action properly within __() construct function...

Here is my code below:

```
class helloWorld{ 

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'action_wwoocommerce_single_product_summary' ) );
    }


    function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary()   {
        return '<br /><h1>Hello World</h1>'; 
    }

}

$Hello_World = new helloWorld();
```

So, I am trying to output  function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() here -> action_wwoocommerce_single_product_summary but the problem is I dont know where to put int $priority in this case...

wp codex:

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

Thanks in advance!!!
Denis

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but as folows from codex:

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

if 2nd parameter $function_to_add is inside class then function add_class need a object. Object is $this parameter. $this parameter is for callback!

But 3rd and 4th parameter are just a variable that passed to add_action function.

In summary

```
//i think that this works fine
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary' ), 10, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn´t work... As soon as add_action is within __construct function it doesn´t work...

Comment: Check your "action_wwoocommerce_single_product_summary" with extra w. I copy/pasted this in my line of code too.

Answer (score 1):

One small thing it may be... There's a typo in your add_action line, as you're calling "action_wwoocommerce_single_product_summary" (note the extra 'w' in woocommerce).